# How to print the complete error strack trace in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I have a function to log errors to a log file if an error occurs during the program execution.

```
string LOG_LEVEL_ERROR = "ERROR";
public function logError(string message){
    var logTime = getTime();

    string strLog = logTime + " - " + LOG_LEVEL_ERROR + " - " + message;
    writeToFile(strLog);
}
```

And its being called as follows. This writes the error messages to a log file successfully.

```
logError("[ERROR] cleanup failed " + e.message);
```

However I need to print the complete error stack trace instead of just the error message, to be more descriptive.

**NOTE: The process is automated and therefore cannot manually publish errors to a log file.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ballerina stack traces are associated only with errors which are thrown. Normally, you'd be returning errors instead of throwing, in which case you won't have a way to get a stack trace. If you really do want a stack trace out of returned errors, you could set the error returned from a function call as the cause of the error you are returning from the current function. Then you can use those chain of causes to build a stack trace of sorts of your own. The below example has both cases: a thrown error and returned error (with causes set).

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    error e = returnedError();
    io:println(e);
    io:println();
    thrownError();
}

function thrownError() {
    test1();
}

function test1() {
    error e = {message: "ERROR from test 2"};
    throw e;
}

function returnedError() returns error {
    error e = test2();
    return {message: "ERROR from test 3", cause: e};
}

function test2() returns error {
    return {message: "ERROR from test 4"};
}
```

The above program will result in the following output.

```
{message:"ERROR from test 3", cause:{message:"ERROR from test 4", cause:null}}

error: ballerina/runtime:CallFailedException, message: call failed
    at main(test.bal:7)
caused by ballerina/runtime:CallFailedException, message: call failed
    at thrownError(test.bal:11)
caused by error, message: eRROR from test 2
    at test1(test.bal:16)
```

Note though, setting the errors as causes still doesn't give you information such as source file and line number.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own error logging function you can use the existing logging support in ballerina:

```
import ballerina/log;

function logError(error e){
   log:printError("Error sending response", err = e);
}
```

To publish the logs to a file, redirect the stderr stream to a file.

```
$ ballerina run program.bal 2> b7a-user.log
```

Find more info [here](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/log.html)

Comment: Hi @Riyafa , the requirement is an automated process and therefore it is not possible to manually publish error logs to a file. The error logs need to be written to file during the program execution itself.

Comment: you could automate it using a shell script.

Comment: As Riyafa mentioned, redirecting should work. But the problem with that is it redirects the whole stderr stream. So it is possible that non-log info could also end up in the log file.